# How to get data from a server periodically in the background using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-architecture-components, android-jobscheduler

I am new to android and I am very confused about which method I should use. I am targeting API level 24 and above. I have used timertask but it turns off after sometimes and does not work on Vivo and Xiamo etc..

1. Which method should I use for doing this task in the background (job scheduler, workmanager, intent service, etc.)?
2. How to use the switch to start and stop background work (start calling server when the switch is on and stop when the switch is off)

Comment: Use AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

1) You should schedule your tasks with `WorkManager` on start of your application. You can do whatever you want in this task.

2) You can add `PreferenceChangeListener` and listen your switch preference.